# Splice or Remove list of elements from JSON Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays, json

I am having a JSON Array Output from REST API like this , I am displaying this items on the HTML  using ng-repeat.

```
var searchresponse = [{
    "items": [{
        "employeeId": "ABC",
        "type": "D",
        "alive": "Yes"

    }, {
        "employeeId": "DEF",
        "type": "D",
        "alive": "Yes"

    }, {
        "employeeId": "NPK",
        "type": "D",
        "alive": "Yes"

    }, {
        "employeeId": "PKN",
        "type": "A",
        "alive": "Yes"
    }],
    "more": false
}];
```

when user tries to delete using selectall/single select i am calling a REST API to remove the  employee id from the db . once i get a successful response i am planning to splice / remove the values that have been selected by the user from the VIEW. I would like to remove the following employeeid and their type,alive removed from the searchresponse

```
 var data1=["ABC","NPK"];
```

Whatever the data1 has corresponding details should be removed from the searchresponse

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-to-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is to eliminate each item from `items` array whose `employeeId` is in `data1`,using `splice` method.

References

- [splice method.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
- [indexOf method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```js
var searchresponse = [{
    "items": [{
        "employeeId": "ABC",
        "type": "D",
        "alive": "Yes"

    }, {
        "employeeId": "DEF",
        "type": "D",
        "alive": "Yes"

    }, {
        "employeeId": "NPK",
        "type": "D",
        "alive": "Yes"

    }, {
        "employeeId": "PKN",
        "type": "A",
        "alive": "Yes"
    }],
    "more": false
}];
var data1=["ABC","DEF"];
var items=searchresponse[0].items;
var i=items.length;
while (i--) {
    if(data1.indexOf(items[i].employeeId)!=-1){
        items.splice(i,1);
    }
}
console.log(searchresponse[0].items);
```

Comment: I tried this and its not entering inside the for loop . Am i missing anything

Comment: Probably `searchresponse[0].items` has length 0.

Comment: Are you sure that `searchresponse` looks like in your post ?

Comment: This is what console.log printed 
Array[1]
0:Object
$$hashKey:"object:16"
employeeId:"ABC"
alive:"YES"
type:"D"
selected:false

Comment: It worked !! I was setting the items value directly  in scoperesponse  . so i assigned  items to scoperesponse  and it worked . thanks a lot

Comment: @ Alexandru-Ionut Mihai - For some reason when i select multiple items , last item is not getting removed . Do you know why ?

Comment: It is Removing only even number of elements  like 0,2,4 . Leaving out 1,3 etc!!